# bitcoins not arrived to the receiver

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

Please help me i don't know what do to.
My friend installed the app and i sent him a payment using the address given by the app without knowing the address is changeable. I sent the bitcoins to this address: 1LtVLn1iGrem6W7vVRz8H48HbJZrbWzFCK. The date was: March 7, 2017. The amount was 0.23985547.  The bitcoins was not transferred to him.

Please help me as soon as you can,
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, what app is your friend using? The tag "bitcoin-wallet-app" is referring to one specific piece of software, is it that one that he is using?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction was already confirmed on Match 7th. Your friend is either lying or has a synchronization problem with their wallet software.

Answer (score 0):

Get your friend to send a report: **Options > Report issue**. It would be helpful if he would include the above transaction ID (as shown in the screenshot) with the report.